# How to fit Matplotlib's stock_img() with Cartopy's NearsidePerspective projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, map-projections, cartopy

I am trying to use Cartopy's proejction NearsidePerspective, but overlaping with the real Earth image provided by Matplotlib, and zooming in a bit by lowering the `satellite_height` parameter. It appears that Cartopy is not able to trim the image properly for this specific type of setting. The image is displayed still oustide of what one would expect to be the map boundaries.

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

# Set Projection
height=3000000 
#height=35785831 # this is the default height
projection=ccrs.NearsidePerspective(central_longitude=120,
                                    central_latitude=78,
                                    satellite_height=height)
# Draw 
ax = plt.axes(projection=projection)
ax.stock_img()
ax.coastlines(resolution='50m')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I combine Matplotlib's stock_img() and this configuration of NearsidePerspective to work properly? Or what would be an alternative way to get the result desired?

I am using Python 3.6 on Jupyter Notebook, Matplotlib 3.0.2, and Cartopy 0.16.0.

Comment: For me the map image is cropped correctly. I'm using Python 3.7 on a mac, with matplotlib version 3.0.3 and cartopy version 0.17.0.

Comment: As @ThomasKühn says, it works as expected.

Comment: Ok, then it is just probably a local setup/version problem. Thank you for the comments. Would you like to answer the question, pasting the correct image? Or should I just delete the question?

Comment: Let's leave it as a question. Especially if you can figure out what exactly caused the problem for you and how to fix it (be it a version upgrade or a setup in Jupyter), you can go ahead and edit my answer (I'll make it a community wiki).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same code on a mac with Python 3.7, Matplotlib 3.0.3, and Cartopy 0.17.0, the image is cropped correctly:

[image: result of the OP's code]

This may either be a version problem or with Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: I would expect a closer zoom for the given parameters. If you compare the outer circle of this image, it contains the entire Greenland, for example, while in the image in the question, only the Northernmost tip of Greenland is shown. Is this a different behaviour of `satellite_height` or did you use a different value?

Comment: I used the same height value that you posted in your example code. Now I also tried with a tenth of that height, which gives a smaller area, which is still cropped correctly.